Anomaly detection multivariate time series
Task
I am trying to detect anomalies in multivariate time series by reconstructing the input data. I then look at the difference between the forecast and the original - a large difference indicates an anomaly.
Assume the model is trained on data without anomalies.
Problem
My forecast is basically perfect - it returns the input data almost exactly. This makes me think that I have formulated the question wrong. If you give the model the correct input does it just return the input?
Note it preforms perfectly on tests data it was not trained on, but is it just returning the input data without doing anything?
An example is

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop


dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'var_of_interest': [0.5, 0.8, 0.4],
    'var1': [0.3,0.4,0.5],
    'var2': [0.7,0.2,0.9]
})


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(dummy_data.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

history = model.fit(dummy_data, dummy_data, epochs=10, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.2)
history
    
px.line(pd.DataFrame(history.history))

Is this a valid approach?
There is a similar approach in the TensorFlow docs
